# failure joining samba AD domain over a slow connection: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT

Tags: ubuntu, samba, active-directory, domain, samba4

Running Ubuntu with Samba 4 (Zentyal 3.5)

Trying to join a new ADC (additional domain controller) to an existing PDC.  Unfortunately I am getting an error, and I **THINK** the error might be caused by the terribly slow connection that the ADC is on (also over a VPN).  Is there a setting that I can change to account for this slow connection?

Here is the command I am running:

```
samba-tool domain join local.mydomain.com DC  
  --username='domain-admin'  
  --workgroup='mydomain'  
  --password='a-cool-password'  
  --server='192.18.1.10'  
  --dns-backend=BIND9_DLZ  
  --realm='LOCAL.MYDOMAIN.COM'  
  --site='Default-First-Site-Name'
```

And here is the result I am getting (scroll to see everything):

```
params.c:pm_process() - Processing configuration file "/etc/samba/shares.conf"  
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered  
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered  
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered  
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered  
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered  
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered  
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered  
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered  
Cannot do GSSAPI to an IP address  
Got challenge flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60898235  
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088235  
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088235  
workgroup is MYDOMAIN  
realm is local.mydomain.com  
checking sAMAccountName  
Adding CN=REMOTE-ADC,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=local,DC=mydomain,DC=com  
Adding CN=REMOTE-ADC,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=local,DC=mydomain,DC=com  
Adding CN=NTDS Settings,CN=REMOTE-ADC,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=local,DC=mydomain,DC=com  
Using binding ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.10[,seal]  
Cannot do GSSAPI to an IP address  
Got challenge flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60898235  
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088235  
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:  
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088235  
Join failed - cleaning up  
checking sAMAccountName  
Deleted CN=REMOTE-ADC,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=local,DC=mydomain,DC=com  
Deleted CN=REMOTE-ADC,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=local,DC=mydomain,DC=com  
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - (-1073741643, 'NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT')`
```

It pauses for quite a while after

`Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x60088235`

before giving me the `Join failed` error...

...so I'm pretty sure that is where the timeout is occurring.

Help?

Comment: This sounds similar to your issue: https://tracker.zentyal.org/issues/689

Comment: I don't think so at all.  There is no NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT error code there.  Also, this issue was reported and supposedly fixed over 3 months ago.  My system is fully updated.

Comment: Seriously, I don't think it is a coincidence that I am getting a TIMEOUT error.  The server is located in the middle of nowhere, Colombia South America and is using a mediocre long-distance Microwave antenna connection to get internet.  My pings to the main domain server stay pretty consistent in the 1000ms - 2000ms range.  There must be a way to allow for high latency during a domain join?

Comment: Don't know. That was the best lead I've found thus far given the info from your Q.